# how to set width auto for all childrens of div while printing using jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used fluid layout in html page.while printing i am facing problems with width and the content is not showing fully in input and text areas.when i set width as auto  for table  the cells alignment is missing. how can I solve this problem

```
@media print {
body {
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 12pt;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0%;
   padding: 0;
}
#target {
    display:none;
}
#printDiv {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto;
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any demo? Any [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? We need the HTML too!!!

Comment: i have created please go through this link http://jsfiddle.net/az3B2/  how can i get the complete data from the inputs and text areas.

Comment: Why do you use tables for layout purpose? Can you switch them to divs?

Comment: Table structure is suitable to my requirement that is why i have used it.Can't we adjust the data  in table structure

Comment: Okay, lemme see and suggest you if something is needed. Is it possible to change? Because, as per latest W3C Guidelines, table structures are outdated.

Comment: Okay in your fiddle, what is the issue you are facing and what browser are you using?

Comment: My browser version is firefox 15.According to monitor size the data is wrapped and whole data is not showing in print page.